# Show that if $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix with $AA^T = 2J + 5I$ then $n \geq m$ ($J$ is matrix of ones)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying for a qualifying exam and I got stuck on this question:

Show that if $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix with $AA^T = 2J + 5I$ then $n \geq m$.

Here $J$ is the matrix of all $1$s. The hint for the problem is to use Fischer's inequality. I was reading about this on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer%27s_inequality) but I fail to see how I can apply this to this problem. I was able to prove the previous part of the problem which was to show that $J$ is diagonalizable and to find the eigenvectors. To prove this is not a homework problem, [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/Grad/QualifyingExams/PDF/2016-01-algebra.pdf) is a link to the practice exam.

I would really appreciate a hint. Thank you

Comment: if $n< m$   then rank $A$ is   at most $n.$ However, $2J + 5 I$ is of full rank $m,$ being symmetric positive definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that $2J+5I$ is invertible. Then
$$m = \mathrm{rank}(AA^T) \le \mathrm{rank}(A) \le \min(m,n).$$